# Would I outdress my boss and get bad looks?

Tags: dress-code, consulting

I like clothing, fashion and style and cannot wait to buy an amazing suit with nice accessories. I worry I will ‘out-dress’ my future boss if I were to buy accessories like a Zegna tie and pocket squares, as well as potentially expensive suits. Is it possible to outdress one's boss?

Comment: *"Would an expensive/high-quality suit be a problem or is it alright if it fits perfectly? "* - be a problem to whom? To you future boss? We can't tell... mind clarifying?

Comment: This is hard to answer. In my company, you'd outdress the boss by wearing something more fancy than a t-shirt, but I don't think anyone would care as long as you're comfortable in your outfit. I'm sure it's different in other places.

Comment: Not to burst your bubble, but it's unlikely anyone would even notice, unless you are dressing drastically differently from the norm (i.e., bizarrely).

Comment: It depends on how conservative your work domain and work environment.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate of the two questions shown in the box, though [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58491/how-to-dress-if-there-is-no-dress-code/58495#58495) might also be worth checking if you're in a place without a real dress-code (though that wouldn't be the case in consulting.) Since you're dealing with a hypothetical 3 years in the future there's little else that can be said here that isn't covered by the linked questions. But if you [edit] this to improve the general nature of the question and focus just on "*Is it possible to overdress?*" that is probably useful.

Comment: Yeah, so what? There are people that are used to wear suits in a meeting room that are more expensive than the suits of everyone else together. So what?

Answer (score 1):

I was always told that a large part of getting ahead in a company is to dress and act as if you run the place.

In business, perception is reality.

Comment: Not in wall street apparently wearing a to expensive watch or even  cufflinks ! can cause problems